# How could a magical enchantment minimize the effect a super dense and super heavy object would have on a floor beneath it?

Tags: magic, physics

In a story that I am writing, there is a specific race that has the ability to increase the density and strength of their muscles without the size of these muscles changing, through the consumption of monster meat. This race also has a focus on strengthening the legs over any other body part, so the legs are even heavier than the the torso and arms put together.

Without putting in much effort and eating a balanced diet with occasional monster meat included, a child could weigh the same as four average human males, 360kg, a female teenager of this race could weigh the same as an African Bush Elephant, 6,000 kg. A decade later, she could weigh the same as an M1 Abrams main battle tank, 54,000 kg. They look like any ordinary human, yet weigh dozens of times more.

This has obvious implications when it comes to the pressure this race would exert onto the ground of a planet. They would pretty much sink through any type of soft ground. No matter if it is metal or stone, the flooring in buildings would suffer. Once they start walking, the ground pressure exerted would double. As a drawback to having great strength, they cannot leave their home planet, which has conditions suited to them.

An individual from one of these races, my main character, acquires clothes with an enchantment that would mitigate effects of their incredible weight from effecting the ground. (Let's ignore the effects that super dense and strong arms would have on door handles and focus solely on the downward force, including the effect the enchantment would have on a chair.)

**My character would eventually reach the weight of 500,000 kg, 500 tons. Then 1000 tons, then 2000 tons, and so on. Not sure of the limit yet.**

Now, ignoring the fact that there are a whole multitude of other problems such as dense ear bones leading to them being hard of hearing as well as having an incredibly high body temperature as a result of more surface area for thermal transfer within the body itself, I would like to know what kind of enchantment would work in this situation and how it would work.

**How could a magical enchantment minimize the effect a super dense and super heavy object would have on a floor beneath it?**

***Here are some ideas that I personally came up with and what I think of them:***

***(The magical enchantment is placed on a piece of clothing, i.e. shoes.)***

-The magical enchantment increases the effective surface area of the feet without actually making the feet bigger, much like snowshoes do but through magical means.
*This may not be effective within a room. This may not be effective in small spaces. This enchantment may effect movement, such as the foot coming down at an angle may cause the increased surface area of the foot to hit the floor. May effect others standing close. It would not assist with furniture. This enchantment most likely begins to fail when my character approaches to 100 tons mark. **Does not seem practically viable.***

-The magical enchantment disperses the weight into the air.
*The air may perhaps feel heavier, it may make breathing difficult. Increases air pressure. The air that is compressed would be replaced by air particles that were originally outside of the sphere of influence, which would also be compressed. Seems incredibly deadly. Although, it would be pretty cool as a sort of aura/pressure ability, as if enemies could actually feel the individuals weight and power through the air becoming heavier. Although cool, still does not seem safe at all. Would also most likely fail in a vacuum situation, as well as when my character reaches even the 10 tons mark. **Does not seem physically or practically viable.***

-The force is completely cancelled out with no real explanation other than magic. Such as the force being shunt off into another dimension.
***Just seems boring.***

-The magical enchantment spreads the force exerted downwards equally into the surrounding flooring, regardless of uneven terrain. As my character reaches the 100 ton mark and beyond, it would most likely exert the force on the entire structure. beneath the characters feet. E.G. a space station.
*This may disregard furniture. When sitting down, a chair may be the only object counted, thus leading to the full force being equally spread onto the chair. This enchantment may spread the downwards force onto any screws or support structures within the flooring which are not supposed to have such a large amount of force hitting it specifically. **Seems the most practically viable, and the fact that the floor may still creek in protest as the individual walks may make for interesting situations. Furniture not being covered, as well as small vehicles, may also make for an interesting restriction within the story.***

**Any other magical enchantments with even a tiny bit of realism would be appreciated. The effects do not need to be completely cancelled out, just turned down to safe levels, e.g. not destroying the flooring as the character walks, perhaps only leaving behind a now slightly more structurally unsafe area due to the now weakened flooring.**

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Your post is asking a lot of different questions. Such posts aren't a good fit for this site. Can you [edit] your post so that it's asking 1 specific answerable question?

Comment: I don't know if this counts as 'dissapearing effect' or not. Why not just have anything in the pants be at zero gravity? Does the character need to be able to walk, or can they have something that suspends the effect but leaves them incapacitated? I like the idea of 'anti-density' where the character finds their super-muscle is unable to function while wearing the special clothes and they're as weak as a small child.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first idea seems ideal to me.

When something like your feet is resting on the ground that same ground resists the pressure. It takes effort to deform the ground, push it further down than it already is because beneath that ground is more ground, and beneath that is the earth mantle, and beneath that there is the partially molten core that is pressing just as hard outwards as all the layers on top are pressing inwards creating an equilibrium where neither moves. And whenever you shift your weight, the pressure becomes a tiny bit higher, everything below it becomes a little bit more compressed until that pressure is at an equilibrium again.

So what you do is simply say "my feet aren't just touching the ground where my physical feet are, they are also touching the ground in a large circle on a horizontal plane compared to the ground".

So if you step halfway up a hill, you will be supported by all the terrain that is at your height in the circumference that you can decide, allowing you to stay there without sagging into the ground as the entire surface area of the piece of hill can handle your weight. Problems would arise when climbing stairs though, although if the walls that support said stairs can support your weight than they will take it and keep you standing without collapsing the stairs.

You could also switch it around. Let's say that the magic works like piles driven into the ground to support houses, or in this case it supports your heavyweights. With every step it basically makes the ground beneath you one single block that is using the solid foundation below the ground to support your weight as well as the pressure from the sides on those piles that keep them in place.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but if it is possible for things to hover, a small circle of wood could be enchanted to hover in a similar manner to a hoverboard, and to have that piece of wood be enchanted so it is either unbreakable or extremely resistant to breaking. A different option would be to enchant the places where your character commonly goes with an enchantment that essentially strengthens it to the point of being mostly unbreakable. If this creature is widespread throughout the world, it may make sense to have that worlds authority figures somehow enchant the entire planet.

Answer (score 0):

The enchantment actually warps gravity in his vicinity.

It warps the gravity in such a fashion that the majority of his mass has its gravity reversed alternating throughout his entire body. Not enough to rip him apart by tidal forces but enough that the real pressure he is exerting on the ground is a fraction of the total. Let's say only 300 lbs/ 500 tons. With the way the enchantment works, however is that it will need adjustment at regular intervals to account for weight gain from more monstie meats.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I would suggest a sort of contained magically induced magnetic levitation that would allow the user to stay on the ground but not actually have many weight issues. This is done by many real life trains to lift them up from the ground and propel them forward.
 The article of clothing this wizard received would most likely be made out of a sort of magical metal that would contain a sort of upwards magnetic force to push the user upwards just enough to reduce or eliminate the strain of the weight on the surrounding terrain. As far as making the terrain underneath the character able to reciprocate the magnetism, it would have to be a double enchantment that would create a magnetic field on surfaces directly underneath the article of clothing on the surface of the walking space.
 Rules for which substances can be walked on with this are negotiable depending on how potent magic is. The enchantment might not be very efficient as far as magic consumption if there isn't a natural absorption feature, so look out for that. Essentially, it wouldn't be an easy change to get used to for the character to walk with padded weight and then there is the added balance that the character would have to develop. The horizontal movement would also be unaffected by the enchantment, but if the direction of the enchantment is changed even slightly, the wizard could fall.
 It would give your wizard the ability to walk without giving the ability to directly fly. Then, the amount of weight that this enchantment reduces is completely up to you.
```

Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Sorry to quibble, but could you break-up your answer into paragraphs. The wall of text is somewhat eyeball-breaking at present. (From review).